# can not upload react project correctly to github

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, github

i have a project in visual studio which contains api project, react project and three class projects. i am trying to push it to github as i normal do. the api project and class projects are pushed but not the client project which is react.

i can see the react file (client pro) on github but can not open it. tried to clone the project but getting an error that says " one or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly"
and in the output window i get  "The project file cannot be found."

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8MDb.gif)

here you can see the client pro is different than the other projects